# Script to execute multiple python files for Windows

Tags: python, for-loop, cmd, windows-scripting

I have a python script (script.py) that requires one file per input (input.txt) and one file per output (output.txt). Plus, the script requires additional data from model.pcl. I execute script through the console. For windows it looks like this:

> type input.txt | python script.py model.pcl output.txt

I would like to apply this script to 10 thousand files and save the result in separate txt files.

I know how to do it with python:

```
import subprocess
for i in range(1, 10001):
    e = 'type input_%s.txt | python script.py model.pcl output/output_%s.txt' % (i,i)
    subprocess.call(e, shell=True)
```

But it is not an ideal solution because in this approach I cannot specify a folder for an input file (input/input_%s.txt). If I try to do it I get an error:

```
the syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Are there other options for a Windows machine?

Comment: Don't double-post! ([Applying python script for multiple files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686513/applying-python-script-for-multiple-files-in-windows)) You already edited the other question, so it's going to be put into a review queue, and it will be reopened after some time when you fixed the issues that caused the original question to be closed...

Comment: @aschipfl Sorry. I thought that my previous question was closed. Maybe is it better if I delete anoter question?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best when you delete the other closed question then...

Comment: `input/input_%s.txt` - did you try specifying the complete path?

Comment: @wwii Yes, I tryed.

Comment: Changing to a backslash instead of a forward slash works for me. - Windows10. `r'type temp\input_%s.txt | python script.py model.pcl output\output_%s.txt' % (i,i)`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue like this in python. It worked for me when I added all the items in a list.

```
import subprocess 
for i in range(1, 10001): 
    e = ['type input_%s.txt | python script.py model.pcl output/output_%s.txt' % (i,i)]
    subprocess.call(e, shell=True)
```

Can you test it and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. it says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Found the reference for how to execute script that way in python.  https://github.com/SugaanthMohan/Python_Tools/blob/master/Execute_Bash_Securely/Secure_Bash.py

Answer (score 0):

This should do the needful from the Windows CMD Prompt:

```
FOR /L %# IN (1,1,10001) DO @TYPE "C:\Path\To\input_%#.txt"   | python script.py model.pcl "C:\Path\To\output_%#.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is something similar to this

```
#Path to all files
path = os.getcwd()
#Puts file names to a variable
files = os.listdir(path)
#Gets just the .txt
txtFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")
```

This would allow you to do all .txt files in a specific folder ideally the one that the script is placed in but that can be asily modified